# Test Component Loading bar Angular

Tags: angular

I want to test my loading bar for a component. Using the router I am switching between components when a nav link is pressed.

Whats an easy way to make a component take a long time to load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a resolver on the route that returns a delayed stream. [This answer mentions doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52762160/10747134).

Here is an example pulled from [Alligator IO](https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/)

```
@Injectable()
export class HnResolver implements Resolve<Observable<string>> {
  constructor() {}

  resolve() {
    return Observable.of('Hello Alligator!').delay(2000);
  }
}
```